# Who is Leilah in Tales of Zestiria the X?

Tags: tales-of-zestiria

I am watching *Tales of Zestiria the X* and I didn't understand if Leilah the Seraphim is the soul of the sword or it's kind of the guardian of that sword that can strengthen it.

Who is she?

Comment: Maybe you should read [this](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Seraph)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having played to the video games what we learn about Leilah is that she is living in the sword waiting for a new "Dôshi" to come.

So Leilah isn't the soul of the sword or here to make it stronger. She's here awaiting a new "Dôshi" and that's why she ask to Sorey why he wants power.

When he answer her right she allows him to use the sword and become is Seraphin.

I would add that I don't think Seraphin lives in objects. But in Tales of Berseria we learn that usually, each Seraphin is linked to one object really important for them. So it's more like a symbol.

**Edit :**

I'll just add the [link](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Seraph) that  Namikaze Sheena mentioned in a comment for those searching more information about Seraphins and not only about Leilah or their link with objects.

Comment: thank you for your answer it made it all clear but don't you think that Namikaze Sheena link will be valuable ?!? in your answer ?!?

Comment: Ok so I didn't understood from your question that you wanted more explanations about the Seraphins because you only ask about the link between Leilah and the sword and not about the Seraphins themselves.
These page only speak about the Seraphins but not about their link with objects or about Leilah.
But I can still add the link in my answer for those searching more infos about Seraphins. ;)

Comment: non you miss understood me your answer is the answer of the question but i only want you to add this link as a valuable link in your answer to make it a perfect one

Comment: you just did it's the point

Comment: But in Berseria (Which is prequel of Zestiria) , Seraphim is not exist yet.

Comment: Malak => Seraphin so I think we can still apply the sames rules. As we can meet Zaveid in Berseria and he is called a Malak while he's a Seraphin later in Zestiria.